# Не могу написать фильтр

Tags: python-3.x, django

Допустим, есть модель вроде:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    delta = 100
    prise = IntegerField()
    recommended_prise = IntegerField()
```

Мне необходимо написать фильтр типа `MyModel.objects.filter(prise - recommended_prise > delta)`, но такой, чтобы работал.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Примерно так (по памяти): `MyModel.objects.filter(prise__gt = F('recommended_prise') + F('delta'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 способ - Александра из комментов вопроса, его дублировать не буду

2 способ - сначала сделать аннотацию (наприме чтобы потом не пересчитывать в питоне снова)

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(the_delta=F('recommended_prise') + F('delta')).filter(the_delta__gt=F('delta'))
```

И зачем это нужно? Если delta - это разница, судя по названиям переменных, по не проще ли ее вычислять через annotate или в питоне? Ее же можно обновлять при сохранении объектов, если поле нужно в модели

Answer (score 1):

Может помочь такой код:

```
objects = MyModel.objects.all()

for object in objects:
    if (object.prise - object.recommended_prise) > o.delta:
        # ваш код тут
        pass
```

Работает это так: с БД берем все записи и просто в цикле проверяем их на соответствие. Костыль, но работает :)

Comment: Костыль - это да, просто я хотел именно правильный вариант таких запросов узнать)